# Как передать переменную в тест match()?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    paths:
      - path-one
      - path-two
      - path-three
    patterns:
      - pat-1
      - pat-2
      - pat-3
      - pat-one


  tasks:
    - name: set empty list
      set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: [  ]

    - set_fact:
        files_to_be_removed: "{{ files_to_be_removed + [ item.1 ] }}"
      when: item.1 is match(".*[item.0].*")
      with_nested:
        - "{{ patterns }}"
        - "{{ paths }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ files_to_be_removed }}"

...
```

Как передать в строчке

```
when: item.1 is match(".*[item.0].*")
```

значение переменной `time.0` ?